# Need to destroy Mesh and Material to avoid leaks in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, memory-leaks, mesh

I’m writing a game in Unity with programmatically created simple GameObjects (colored cubes), which each have their own Material and Mesh and may also have child GameObjects. I have found that I have memory leaks for Mesh and Material whenever a cube is removed. So I have developed the method below which does fix the problem.

But is this sensible? What do other people do? And are there any other GameObject Components I should worry about that may also cause leaks.

```
private static void DestroyGameObject(GameObject gameObject)
{
    int numberOfChildren = gameObject.transform.childCount;
    for (int index = 0; index < numberOfChildren; index++)
    {
        GameObject child = gameObject.transform.GetChild(index).gameObject;
        CubeWallView.DestroyGameObject(child); // Recursive
    }
    //
    Renderer renderer = gameObject.GetComponent<Renderer>();
    if (renderer != null)
    {
        Material[] materials = renderer.sharedMaterials;
        if (materials != null)
        {
            foreach (Material material in materials)
            {
                UnityEngine.Object.Destroy(material);
            }
        }
    }
    //
    MeshFilter meshFilter = gameObject.GetComponent<MeshFilter>();
    if (meshFilter != null)
    {
        Mesh mesh = meshFilter.sharedMesh;
        if (mesh != null)
        {
            UnityEngine.Object.Destroy(mesh);
        }
    }
    //
    UnityEngine.Object.Destroy(gameObject);
}
```

Comment: According to the documentation of the `Destroy` method, it destroys a `GameObject` as well as all of its components and child objects. So al the code above _should_ not be necessary. Are you keeping any references to the mesh and material objects anywhere else in your code?
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Destroy.html

Comment: I'm not keeping other references to mesh and material. I think Material and Mesh are different. See: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Renderer-material.html where it says "It is your responsibility to destroy the materials when the game object is being destroyed". It also mentions "Resources.UnloadUnusedAssets" but with a slighty obscure comment about using it only when loading a new level which put me off using it.

Comment: In that case, it looks like there's no way around doing it manually. I suggest you make a `MonoBehaviour` where the `OnDestroy` method also destroys the material/mesh of the game object. Assuming you always have a `Renderer` or `MeshFilter` component on your game object, you don't have to check if the component exists and if you never change the component during the object's lifetime, you can even create a private field to cache the `GetComponent` result.